# Can the thead joinable-join have a race condition? how do you get around it?

Tags: c++, stdthread

Lets say I have the following class

```
 class A
 {
 public:
    A()
    {
       my_thread=std::thread(std::bind(&A::foo, this));
    }
    ~A()
    {
       if (my_thread.joinable())
       {
          my_thread.join();
       }
    }
 private:
    std::thread my_thread;
    int foo();
 };
```

Basically, if my thread completes between the joinable and join calls, then `my_thread.join` will wait forever? How do you get around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Basically, if my thread completes between the `joinable` and `join` calls, then `my_thread.join` will wait forever?

No. A thread is still joinable after it has completed; it only becomes unjoinable once it has been joined or detached.

All threads must be joined or detached before the controlling `thread` object is destroyed.

Comment: Keeping in mind that thread objects can be moved (which changes which thread object is the controlling thread object).